# Migrating from ef6 to postgresql in visual studio

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio, entity-framework

I am new to PostgreSQL and as a company, we have found out that PostgreSQL is better than SQL Server on processing online transactions and we have reached a conclusion to migrate from SQL Server to PostgreSQL.

I have bought DBConvert to successfully migrate the database from MS SQL Server to PostgreSQL and that is just fine, all data has been transferred. Now, the problem comes when I now have to move my visual studio from EF to PostgreSQL. I have researched how best I could really do this. This Article is not detailed enough:

[Migrate EF6 database-first from SQL Server to PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54018599/migrate-ef6-database-first-from-sql-server-to-postgresql)

An several aren't detailed enough. Can anyone assist me in a step-by-step approach on how best I could do this?

Comment: Here is a related thread you can refer to:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57412639/how-to-manage-the-migration-sqlserver-to-postgresql-with-npgsql

Comment: Hi DanielZhang-MSFT, I can't seem to get an answer from the Blog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally found that the only way to successfully move from Visual Studio Entity Framework to PostgreSQL, you have to use the Code First Approach.

There is no scaffolding solution I found to do the conversion. You will have to install the Npgsql Provider, change the connection string to point to PostgreSQL, and also install the Npgsql.EntityFramwework and make sure your models have been changed accordingly.